# Why we assigned the the value of variable "option" 1 before loops?

Tags: python

I'm a new to programming and I chose python as my first language because its easy. But I'm confused here with this code:

```
option = 1 
while option != 0:
    print "/n/n/n************MENU************" #Make a menu
    print "1. Add numbers"
    print "2. Find perimeter and area of a rectangle"
    print "0. Forget it!"
    print "*" * 28

    option = input("Please make a selection: ") #Prompt user for a selection      
    if option == 1: #If option is 1, get input and calculate 
        firstnumber = input("Enter 1st number: ")
        secondnumber = input("Enter 2nd number: ") 
        add = firstnumber + secondnumber
        print firstnumber, "added to", secondnumber, "equals", add #show results  

    elif option == 2: #If option is 2, get input and calculate
        length = input("Enter length: ")
        width = input("Enter width: ")
        perimeter = length * 2 + width * 2
        area = length * width
        print "The perimeter of your rectangle is", perimeter #show results       
        print "The area of your rectangle is", area

    else: #if the input is anything else its not valid
        print "That is not a valid option!"
```

Okay Okay I get every thing below the `Option` variable. I just want to know why we assigned the value of `Option=1`, why we added it on the top of the program ,and what is its function. Also can we change its value. Please make me understand it in simple language as I'm new to programming.

Comment: You couldn't understand the `option = 1 ` line ( a simple variable initialization) and you're saying : **I get every thing below the "Option" variable**, how's that possible?

Answer (score 4):

If you didn't create the variable `option` at the start of the program, the line

```
 while option != 0:
```

would break, because no `option` variable would yet exist.

As for how to change its value, notice that it is changed every time the line:

```
option = input("Please make a selection: ")
```

happens- that is reassigning its value to the user's input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but why did we assign its value 1?

Comment: @user1977722: You can assign its value to anything except `0` and it makes no difference. If you assigned it to be `0`, the `while` loop would never execute (since `option != 0` would be false). Try giving it the value `2`, `3`, `100`, or `"hello"` and you will see it makes no difference (`1` is just a convenient value)

Comment: the value assigned the first time does not matter as long as it is not 0 since it is overwritten in the line with `input`. The important thing is it must exists before the `while` line.

Comment: Anything which doesn't compare equal to zero, that is -- `False == 0`, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: That helped thanks. But i have got another problem here with this code:

counter = input("Enter a number to start the countdown: ")

for x in range(counter, 0, -1):
    print x 

print "SPLAT
what is x here and can we change its value? or name? like i will assign y or any other variable there?

Comment: Reassigning its value? You mean like `x = 2`? (I don't know what you mean by "reassign its name")

Answer (score 2):

So that the while statement below it doesn't try to check a non-existent name. It doesn't *have* to be assigned `1`, it just happens to be the first non-zero natural number.

Answer (score 0):

Python requires variables to be declared before they can be used.

In this case, a decision is being made whether `option` is set to `1` or `2` (so we set it to one of those values, ordinarily we could just as easily set it to `0` or an empty string). While some languages are less stringent on variable declaration (PHP comes to mind), most require variables to exist prior to use.

Python does not require variables to be explicitly declared, only that they are given a value to reserve memory space. VB.NET, by default, on the other hand, requires variables to be explicitly declared...

```
Dim var as D
```

Which sets the variables `type` but doesn't give it an initial value.

See [the Python docs](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_variable_types.htm).